# как при отправке формы времени, запретить запись если уже существует указаное время

Tags: javascript, dom, время, сравнение, проверка

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<input type="time" id="myTime">
<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>
<p id="result"></p>
 </form>
<script> 

/*нужна функция если у нас например уже есть запись на
 13.00 то при следующей отправки формы если 13.00 
уже занято,высветлялась просьба вписать другое время*/   
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTime").value;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x; }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Где и в каком виде хранятся записи?

Comment: save : function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
      
    cal.data[cal.sDay] = document.getElementById("evt-details").value+"<br>"+document.getElementById("myTime").value;
  
    localStorage.setItem("cal-" + cal.sMth + "-" + cal.sYear, JSON.stringify(cal.data));
    cal.list();
  }

Comment: Уточнять/дополнять вoпрос надо реадактированием, а не в комментариях (как минимум потому что комментарии тут иногда пропадают из-за тревог) - отредактировать можно нажав текстовую кнопку "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1312463/edit)" под вoпросом.